# HTML iframe change height event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have appended an iFrame to a div. I am changing the height of the div on iframe's load event (using jQuery).

The problem is that in the iframe there are a lots of text fields, and when the user enters large amounts of text, they become multi-line (at the beginning they are one line text fields). So, because new lines are added, the iframe height expands, but the load event of iframe does not catch this.

What is the best way (thinking about performance) to change the div height when - because of some event - the iframe height is changed?

I have considered binding onchange function of each textfield but I do not like this, because sometimes I will have functions already bound to those fields?

Comment: So what? You can add multiple event listeners for the same event type to a single element. You don't use the tragically outdated `onchange` method, do you?

Comment: @MaxArt, I hope there is more good way to do this. I know that I can bind as many as I like events to one element, but I do not think this is a good solution leading to good performance.

Comment: @Joro Have you actually tested its performance? How many text fields does that iframe contains anyway? Maybe you can listen the 'resize' event of the iframe body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#frame_id").height($("#frame_id").contents().find("html").height());
```

Comment: Yeah, I have already done this. But I need to change the height of the parent element when the height of the Iframe is change dynimically.

Comment: Then in similar way, what about `$('#parent_ele_id').height($('#frame_id').height());` or nesting/merging it with above code, huh?

Answer (score 0):

you can hook the resize code to a setInterval with lets say 500ms, it wont have a heavy impact on performance.
Also you can turn that code ON onfocus and turn it OFF onblur.

Comment: I do not think that checking the size of the iframe on every  half second is good idea, but i will try this. Thanks.